# How to save complete TensorFlow model while using official TensorFlow object detection API on Retinanet

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-model-garden

I am trying to save the complete model using model.save (instead of only checkpoints) at the end of training steps while using official retinanet object detection API. However, I am getting the below error when model.save is called:

```
I0414 17:18:52.661234 140283524683584 distributed_executor.py:49] Saving model as TF checkpoint: /home/ubuntu/ankur/models/official/vision/detection/ModelDIr/ctl_step_5.ckpt-1
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1786: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
W0414 17:19:26.865248 140283524683584 deprecation.py:506] From /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:1786: calling BaseResourceVariable.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) with constraint is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
If using Keras pass *_constraint arguments to layers.
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: /home/ubuntu/ankur/models/official/vision/detection/saved_model/test_model/assets
I0414 17:19:33.264274 140283524683584 builder_impl.py:775] Assets written to: /home/ubuntu/ankur/models/official/vision/detection/saved_model/test_model/assets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 235, in <module>
    app.run(main)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "main.py", line 230, in main
    run()
  File "main.py", line 224, in run
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "main.py", line 117, in run_executor
    save_config=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/ankur/models/official/modeling/training/distributed_executor.py", line 480, in train
    model.save('/home/ubuntu/ankur/models/official/vision/detection/saved_model/test_model')
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 1008, in save
    signatures, options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 115, in save_model
    signatures, options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/saved_model/save.py", line 78, in save
    save_lib.save(model, filepath, signatures, options)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py", line 923, in save
    saveable_view, asset_info.asset_index)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/save.py", line 647, in _serialize_object_graph
    concrete_function, saveable_view.captured_tensor_node_ids, coder)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/function_serialization.py", line 70, in serialize_concrete_function
    coder.encode_structure(structured_outputs))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/nested_structure_coder.py", line 95, in encode_structure
    return self._map_structure(nested_structure, self._get_encoders())
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/nested_structure_coder.py", line 79, in _map_structure
    return do(pyobj, recursion_fn)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/nested_structure_coder.py", line 203, in do_encode
    encoded_dict.dict_value.fields[key].CopyFrom(encode_fn(value))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/nested_structure_coder.py", line 79, in _map_structure
    return do(pyobj, recursion_fn)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/saved_model/nested_structure_coder.py", line 203, in do_encode
    encoded_dict.dict_value.fields[key].CopyFrom(encode_fn(value))
TypeError: 3 has type int, but expected one of: bytes, unicode
```

Only change that I have made in order to save the complete model is to add the command model.save('/home/ubuntu/ankur/models/official/vision/detection/saved_model/test_model') at the end of training in distributed_executor.py found at the path ~/models/official/modeling/training. Kindly suggest what can be the issue.

TensorFlow version- 2.1
GIThub [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/official/vision/detection/main.py)